# Easily print out a spaces between larger data outputs in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I'm grepping through a very large web directory, and when I do multiple greps in a row, when scrolling up, it is difficult to tell when one result ends and an other one starts. I tried just `clear`, although it sets the scroll bar lower, it still leaves the previous call if you scroll up high enough, so I've been solving this by simply holding return to generate a large amount of blank prompts between each run.

Is there any tools built into linux or bash that solves this issue at all, or am I stuck holding return for a few seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yes "" | head -n 10
```

adjust "10" as required.

For maximum ease of use:

```
blank() { yes "" | head -n "$1"; }
blank 20
```